# Special characters in combo box in xpages

Tags: combobox, xpages, ssjs

I am using combobox to display different departments based on selected locations. Once department is selected system display all sections of related department. When department contains special character e.g. &, / than selected value of department is displayed at front end but when i tries to getComponent value than it's showing only old selected value. I am using IBM Notes 9.0.

Can anybody guide me what is issue of special character in combobox ? and any solution or workaround of this issue.

thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Qaiser Abbas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the value from the underlying datasource field or Scope Variable instead of from the component it self. That should solve your problem